# NVIDIA GTX 1050ti overheats when training neural nets

Tags: gpu

When I'm training neural nets on laptop, my gpu gets 95c and laptop becomes very hot. Is it safe ? Do I need to underclock ?

Answer (score 1):

A 1050ti at 95 degrees is definitely overheated. Try increasing your fan speed curve or going into the Nvidia control panel and changing the power settings to optimal/balanced rather then maximum.